# Is Angulars detectChanges() and markForCheck() relevant for the default change detection strategy?

Tags: angular

I found in some code of my colleagues detectChanges() and markForCheck(). They are using the default change detection strategy and no NgZones. As far as I know detectChanges and markForCheck is only necessary if you use OnPush strategy or NgZones.

As far as I know these are the  use cases for the methods:
detectChanges => if you are using runOutsideAngular for example () or somethink like getElementById() and manipulate and element (which should be avoided in angular)

markForCheck => if an object was mutating + OnPush strategy

So is Angulars detectChanges() and markForCheck() relevant for the default change detection strategy?

Answer (score 2):

Yesn't.

If you're not using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` or `ChangeDetectorRef`, then both of the methods won't do anything.

You can however, detach the change detector, even with default change detection.
in that case you can use `detectChanges()` to manually check the view.

Read more about change detection [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef).

Comment: they are also not detaching the change detector. They just use the default change detection strategy together with MarkForCheck or detectChanges. But I don't understand the purpose. They also don't use NgZones or any JQuery. 
Maybe the markForCheck() calls are necessary

Comment: @IsaacTack If there are no additional shenanagans, most likely they do nothing. I'd suggest simply asking your colleagues why they used it in the first place.

Comment: I think they also not so sure about that :-)